# Mysql word boundary for diacritic strings

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I am facing an issue to match words with word boundaries in diacritic strings

```
CREATE TABLE `authors` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `initials` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `affiliation_available` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_names` (`first_name`,`last_name`,`initials`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

INSERT INTO `authors` VALUES (1,'Juan José','Palacios Gutiérrez','JJ',1);

I want to get the word boundaries for diacritic strings also

select * from authors where ( preg_rlike('/\bJosé\b/i',CONVERT(authors.first_name USING utf8)));

Which failes, then I tried

select * from authors where ( preg_rlike('/(?<!\w)José(?!\w)/i',CONVERT(authors.first_name USING utf8)));

It is working. But

select * from authors where ( preg_rlike('/(?<!\w)Jos(?!\w)/i',CONVERT(authors.first_name USING utf8)));

This query should return false ideally.Because there is no words with Jos.But here it returns the wrong data

Can you please help me

Comment: Which version of MySQL/MariaDB?  Did you install a different regexp handler?

Comment: mysql version 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, different regexp handler means?

Comment: MariaDB handles `(?...`, MySQL does not.